# NAudio - control which ACM codec used

Tags: c#, windows, naudio, codec

I'm using NAudio to convert mp3 to WAV, using the `WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream()` method.

As I understand it, this asks the OS about the available ACM codecs and then chooses one.

How do I control which ACMs are used, or set a priority for them? Is there an option for that in the Windows OS or in NAudio?

Currently it seems to be using the ones that come with Windows Media Player, and they fail for certain mp3s that play/convert fine in other places.

Basically I want to tell it to use a decent codec.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood it calls [acmFormatSuggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to try to find its way to a conversion to PCM. You can actually set the priority in Windows for each installed ACM. I used to know how to get to this in Windows XP but I don't know where Windows 7 keeps the equivalent dialog. There are ways to specify exactly which ACM driver you want using [acmDriverEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742890%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [acmDriverOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742894%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I did implement this capability for ACM filters (i.e. effects not codecs) with an extra constructor on the `AcmStream` class to allow a driver Id and a `WaveFilter` to be passed in. You could try calling this with a null WaveFilter and the driver Id of your selected ACM codec using `AcmDriver.EnumerateAcmDrivers` or `AcmDriver.FindByShortName`. I'm afraid I didn't put a constructor onto `WaveFormatConversionStream` that let you pass in your own `AcmDriver` though, so you'd have to make your own mod.

Also, what MP3s does it fail for, and what is the error message? It may be an MP3 frame parsing issue rather than the codec. Also, NAudio has an alternative MP3 frame decoder - the `DmoMp3FrameDecompressor`, which may give better results although isn't available on XP.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll look into what you suggest. The error is `System.FormatException: Not a recognised MP3 block at NAudio.Wave.Mp3Frame..ctor(Stream input) at NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader..ctor(Stream inputStream)` but the mp3 will then play ok in Foobar2000 for example, so I figure it must be the codec? Happens for about 1 in 30 mp3s, I can't see what the pattern is though.

Comment: It's not an error from the codec in this case. What version of NAudio are you using? I have made some updates to Mp3FileReader to be a lot more tolerant of incorrectly formatted blocks. If you can submit an example MP3 that fails to me, I can use it as part of the NAudio tests (obviously I will not publicly publish it).

Comment: Might be worth testing with NAudio 1.4, or building latest from Source Control. MP3FileReader is much simpler to use from v1.4 onwards as you don't need to do WaveFormatConversionStream or BlockAlignReductionStream afterwards